Create react context with setter
I create a context like :
const Context = createContext({
                error: "",
  setError: () => {},
});

Everything work
I can call asyncfn.catch((err) => setError("myerr")); into child component.
And I can see the value into error context variable.
But I use typescript and tsc.
When running tsc I get Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. 
I try to use an arg on setError fn, setError(val: string) => {}  but get another issue, val is unused.
I don't know how to fix this issue

Type has to be defined correctly, so you are going the right direction. But you probably do not want to have unused variables in your logic. So better define a type, which indicates that setError expects an argument.
Can you define the type of your context using generics. Like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQYQgO2wA94BfOAMyghDgHJ0NkY6BuAKHeQIGd49CaEnAC8KRtgHEYAHgTs4iuACI0UalGVwAXHD5Rg+AOYAaBUp5oYAUXXQdcABQA3DABsH+w0YCUogHxwzhDAACbspP6O8kqxcbFqGrrKymaKljZ2ULqOfiKBCKRmpD4cnEA Let me know if it helps and will write up an answer

Yes, you fix my issue, thanks !

Defining the types is the right direction. All you have to do is not TypeScript not auto infer the type of context.
If you let that happen then TS infers the type of setError as setError: () => void;.

But, if you explicitly define the type of context using generics, then TS can understand that you expect a string argument val.
Change your code to pass a generic parameter.
import { createContext } from 'react';

const Context = createContext<{
    "error" : string,
    setError : (val : string) => void
}>({
  error: "",
  setError: () => {},
});


Playground
